# Can’t invert a matrix, HP Prime calculator

Tags: matrices

I have a problem when I want to invert a matrix in my HP Prime; the inverse is zero. Meanwhile I can do it in my HP 50g calculator.

Please, give me some clues about this matrix which don’t let invert it, because I want to use the inverse of this matrix to continue my calculations.

Is there any way to get a valid solution in this calculator? My professor told that we have to rewrite the matrix element by element, then to procede to invert.

The matrix is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
407107.73&0&-407107.73\\
0&407107.73&0\\
-407107.73&0&35178678.99
\end{bmatrix}$$

[image: Prime]
[image: 50g]

Comment: Where do the numbers come from?  Try factoring out $407107.73$ first and inverting the result, $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1&0&-1\\0&1&0\\-1&0&\approx86.41\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.  It is obvious that the matrix is invertible as the columns are clearly linearly independent of one another.

Comment: If your question is why a specific calculator model has difficulty with inverting a matrix, it is likely due to the size of the numbers involved.  Again, factoring out the common factor of $407107.73$ should help alleviate that problem.

Comment: The last image is showing a correct result (or near correct one) - What is the problem then?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have to use the inverse to continue calculations, but the matrix is zero; and I can’t use it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

You did not tell us what error or message was displayed when you attempted to calculate the inverse.

Since the result is very small for some enteries, the system could have assumed that the entry is zero, leading to a calculation problem.

See if you can set the precision on the calculator (I doubt that you could, but maybe).

The inverse is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks invertible? The determinant of the matrix $ \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 & b \\ 0 & c & 0 \\ d & 0 & e \end{bmatrix}$ should be $ace - bcd$.

Comment: Right, the sign of the permutation for $bcd$ is $-1$. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use that $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&1&0\\-1&0&x\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{x}{x-1}&0&\frac{1}{x-1}\\0&1&0\\\frac{1}{x-1}&0&\frac{1}{x-1}\end{bmatrix}$ for $x\neq 1$ (*and the inverse doesn't exist for $x=1$*).

This can be shown using standard methods.  Now, account for the extra factor of $407107.73$ and plug in your value of $x$ and conclude.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant is $5.76293\times 10^{18}$. Either the numerical precision of both calculators are different or they use different algorithms.

BTW you may have better luck inverting $({1\over 407107.73})A$.